# What did program compatibility troubleshooter on Windows 10 do to make the program work?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

We have a CSharp Winforms 32 bit program which works fine on Windows 7, 8 and 10.

Our config file has the following:
supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"

There is one particular user on whose Windows 10 x64 laptop the program repeatedly became unresponsive after a while with Event AppHangB1 and Hang type: Top level window is idle

We then ran the Program Compatibility troubleshooter. The compatibility troubleshooter said that our program is incompatible for Windows 10 and applied a fix.

It changed the Compatibility setting to run the program in Compatibility mode for Windows 8.

Since then, the program is working perfectly fine without a single code change.

What we are trying to figure out is, what this setting really means at a code level. Any idea what could be the reason that the program is flagged as incompatible on Windows 10?

Thank you!

Comment: Deadlock is a very common bug, the kind of bug that rarely bytes while testing the app.  Especially common in Winforms, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25977376/17034

Comment: Hi, we did review all the code that would touch UI. After removing all the contention points, it still had issues on windows 10 default. With compatibility mode Windows 8, not a single instance of problem. Just wondering what optimization windows do to make it work.

Comment: You might study ACT and use that to reveal compatibility issues of your application, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/cc722367(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN Actually when it hangs, capture hang dumps and analyze. That's quicker to reveal the culprit.

Comment: Great. Will try to use ACT to check the issue. Thank you!